# Carbohydrates with two hydroxyl group on one carbon atom?

Tags: carbohydrates

Every carbohydrate I keep encountering so far has only one hydroxyl (–OH) group attached to every carbon atom in the carbon chain (in Fischer projections): either on the left, or on the right of the carbon, but never both.

This makes me wonder:
Are there any carbohydrates with –OH groups on *both* sides?
If there aren't, *why*? Is there any physical or chemical rule that would prevent this?

According to this website:
http://colapret.cm.utexas.edu/courses/Nomenclature_files/alcohols.htm
it seems to be possible for *alcohols* to have two –OH groups on one carbon:

> Many compounds have more than one hydroxyl group; two hydroxyl groups are called "diols". If the hydroxyl groups are on adjacent carbons, then it is called a "glycol." If the hydroxyl groups are on the same carbon, then it is called a "gem" (for geminal, or twin) diol.

so what about *carbohydrates*?

Comment: Geminal diols are generally unstable with respect to loss of water (forming an aldehyde/ketone instead). This is generally true whether it's a carbohydrate or some other alcohol. Exceptions are rare. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geminal_diol

Comment: Besides the examples  of geminal diols cited in orthocresol's link, ninhydrin also comes to mind.

Comment: Uhh....glucose?